# Set 1,5 line spacing in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

The document I have to write needs to have a 1,5 line spacing both in normal text and in footnotes.

Now, if I use this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

what I get is this:

[image]

As you see the footnote ignores the spacing of the rest of the document.

If I try to space the footnote this way instead:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\begin{spacing}{1.5}\lipsum[1]\end{spacing}}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

what I get is this:

[image]

In this case the footnote actually *is* spaced correctly, but the note's number is put in a separate line. What I suspect is happening here is that, by trying to format the footnote this way, the number isn't formatted as the rest of the text, and is then considered to be a different paragraph. So what I get is a footnote divided into two paragraphs, one of them including only the one and not-having the 1,5 spacing, and the second one containing the actual text and having the 1,5 spacing.

Of course I'd like the note number to be with the rest of the note.

Someone here knows a way to do such thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `setspace` makes some work just to avoid footnotes having increased leading.

If you want a devastatingly awful document (I know, it's not your fault, but the institution's rules you have to comply with), then just issue

```
\linespread{1.5}
```

before `\begin{document}` and don't load `setspace`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

---

By the way, you shouldn't be enclosing the whole document in a `spacing` environment, but simply issue

```
\setstretch{1.5}
```

if you eventually decide to use `setspace`.

Comment: Eh, here in Italy there's this awful tradition regarding the line spacing in thesis... Anyway, turns out this was what i was trying to do. Thank you ;)

Comment: @user46007 *Not* at my department, of course. ;-)

Comment: I'd been using `\linespread` before the document declaration for quite a while - It seems I just hadn't had enough footnotes before to really notice the problem. `\setstretch` is indeed a big improvement for a footnote heavy document!

Answer (score 10):

If you're managing this as a one-off thing, you could just use

```
...\footnote{\setstretch{1.5}...}...
```

Alternatively, you can add `\setstretch{1.5}` as part of the `\footnotelayout` (supplied by the [`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package):

```
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.5}}
```

Here is an example using the latter suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.5}}% Footnotes are \setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.5}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I deleted one of the } i \setstretch{1.5}}. By the way if I copy your code it works too. Thank you for the answer ;)